# PYSPARK: how to visualize a GraphFrame?

Tags: python, apache-spark, graph, pyspark, graphframes

Suppose that I have created the following graph. My question is how can I visualize it?

```
 # Create a Vertex DataFrame with unique ID column "id"
    v = sqlContext.createDataFrame([
      ("a", "Alice", 34),
      ("b", "Bob", 36),
      ("c", "Charlie", 30),
    ], ["id", "name", "age"])
    # Create an Edge DataFrame with "src" and "dst" columns
    e = sqlContext.createDataFrame([
      ("a", "b", "friend"),
      ("b", "c", "follow"),
      ("c", "b", "follow"),
    ], ["src", "dst", "relationship"])
    # Create a GraphFrame
    from graphframes import *
    g = GraphFrame(v, e)
```

Comment: Alex : are you asking about visualization tools, techniques etc...   to visualize graph frames? then you can see notebook interfaces. see  [On-Time Flight Performance with GraphFrames for Apache Spark](https://databricks.com/blog/2016/03/16/on-time-flight-performance-with-graphframes-for-apache-spark.html)

Comment: @RamGhadiyaram I want to visualize the graph preferably using a spark/python library. If there is no such thing using a tool

Answer (score 5):

Using Python/PySpark/Jupyter I am using the draw functionality from the networkx library. The trick is to create a networkx graph from the grapheframe graph

```py
import networkx as nx
from graphframes import GraphFrame

def PlotGraph(edge_list):
    Gplot=nx.Graph()
    for row in edge_list.select('src','dst').take(1000):
        Gplot.add_edge(row['src'],row['dst'])

    plt.subplot(121)
    nx.draw(Gplot, with_labels=True, font_weight='bold')


spark = SparkSession \
    .builder \
    .appName("PlotAPp") \
    .getOrCreate()

sqlContext = SQLContext(spark)

vertices = sqlContext.createDataFrame([
  ("a", "Alice", 34),
  ("b", "Bob", 36),
  ("c", "Charlie", 30),
  ("d", "David", 29),
  ("e", "Esther", 32),
("e1", "Esther2", 32),
  ("f", "Fanny", 36),
  ("g", "Gabby", 60),
    ("h", "Mark", 61),
    ("i", "Gunter", 62),
    ("j", "Marit", 63)], ["id", "name", "age"])

edges = sqlContext.createDataFrame([
  ("a", "b", "friend"),
  ("b", "a", "follow"),
  ("c", "a", "follow"),
  ("c", "f", "follow"),
  ("g", "h", "follow"),
  ("h", "i", "friend"),
  ("h", "j", "friend"),
  ("j", "h", "friend"),
    ("e", "e1", "friend")
], ["src", "dst", "relationship"])

g = GraphFrame(vertices, edges)
PlotGraph(g.edges)
```

[plot of some graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ylz9i.png)

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't find any native GraphFrame library that visualizes data either.

Nevertheless, you could try to do it from DataBricks with the display() function. You can see an example [here](https://databricks.com/blog/2016/03/16/on-time-flight-performance-with-graphframes-for-apache-spark.html).

Also, you can try to transform the GraphFrame to python lists and use the [matplotlib](http://matplotlib.org/) or the [Pygraphviz](http://pygraphviz.github.io/) libraries.