# How to display/visualize a graph created by GraphFrame?

Tags: pyspark, visualization, graphframes

I have created a graph using GraphFrame

`g = GraphFrame (vertices, edges)`

Apart from analyzing the graph using the queries and the properties offered by the GraphFrame, I would like to visualize the graph to use in a presentation.

Do you know of any tool/library / API / code that allows this visualization in a simple way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not a simple way, but you can use python-igraph library, https://igraph.org/. I used it from R but python should be similar. See simple example below. The main problem with all that tool, you should carefully select small subgraph to draw.

Install it:

```
#>pip install python-igraph
```

The simplest visualisation:

```
g = GraphFrame (vertices, edges)
from igraph import *
ig = Graph.TupleList(g.edges.collect(), directed=True)
plot(ig)
```

Answer (score 2):

Another way is to use the plot functionality from the graph module networkx

```
import networkx as nx
from graphframes import GraphFrame

def PlotGraph(edge_list):
    Gplot=nx.Graph()
    for row in edge_list.select('src','dst').take(1000):
        Gplot.add_edge(row['src'],row['dst'])

    plt.subplot(121)
    nx.draw(Gplot)


spark = SparkSession \
    .builder \
    .appName("PlotAPp") \
    .getOrCreate()

sqlContext = SQLContext(spark)

vertices = sqlContext.createDataFrame([
  ("a", "Alice", 34),
  ("b", "Bob", 36),
  ("c", "Charlie", 30),
  ("d", "David", 29),
  ("e", "Esther", 32),
("e1", "Esther2", 32),
  ("f", "Fanny", 36),
  ("g", "Gabby", 60),
    ("h", "Mark", 61),
    ("i", "Gunter", 62),
    ("j", "Marit", 63)], ["id", "name", "age"])

edges = sqlContext.createDataFrame([
  ("a", "b", "friend"),
  ("b", "a", "follow"),
  ("c", "a", "follow"),
  ("c", "f", "follow"),
  ("g", "h", "follow"),
  ("h", "i", "friend"),
  ("h", "j", "friend"),
  ("j", "h", "friend"),
    ("e", "e1", "friend")
], ["src", "dst", "relationship"])

g = GraphFrame(vertices, edges)
PlotGraph(g.edges)
```

see also [PYSPARK: how to visualize a GraphFrame?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45720931/pyspark-how-to-visualize-a-graphframe/57784880#57784880)

Answer (score 0):

Tried the `igraph` solution, but `plot(ig)` raised an error: `AttributeError: Plotting not available; please install pycairo or cairocffi`.

So I just saved the graph as SVG, this worked fine:

```
ig.write_svg('/tmp/ig.svg')
```

Cheers